# How to Write Series in FreeMarker?

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to write a Numeric and Alphabetic Series in Free-marker. However I am not able to implement it.

I have tried various portal and Freemarker website itself, but was not able to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <#assign count = 0>
   <#assign seq = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',]>
   <#list params_list as test_param> 
       ${count}   ${seq[count]}
        <#assign count = count + 1> 
   </#list>
```

It will print data in

```
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

Comment: This can be simplified with `?lower_abc` and `?counter`; see my answer. (The 0-based item index can be get with `?index`, but since you don't actually need the a-b-c sequence, you won't need it here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?lower_abc` (or `?upper_abc`) to convert a number to a letter, where 1 corresponds to letter "a". If this is inside `#list`, then you can get the 1-based item counter with `itemVariable?counter`. For example:

```
<#list items as item> 
  ${item?counter} ${item?counter?lower_abc}
</#list>
```